# setting permission for executable file output of gcc

Tags: 12.04, gcc, chmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to 'chmod' on an NTFS ( or FAT32 ) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)
>   [Can't make a file executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152607/cant-make-a-file-executable)

i m pretty new to linux and gcc. i have a file1.s file which i tried to build using gcc with following command -

```
gcc -m32 -o file1 file1.s runtime.c
```

compilation was successful and i got the file1, but on issuing

```
./file1
```

does nothing. when i checked the file permissions, i see that for user, only read and write are enabled, executable is set as -.

i tried doing `chmod u+x file1`, but that didnt change any permission.

where am i going wrong? how do i execute this file1? it would just print the sum of two numbers.

thanks!

Comment: `chmod u+x file1` should do the trick. What does `ls -l file1` say after you ran `chmod u+x file1`?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch - it stays the same, that is the execution right is not added even after doing the chmod.

Comment: What file system are you using? `chmod` doesn't work on NTFS, FAT ans similar file systems as they do not support Unix permissions.

Comment: ohh... i am using ntfs in that drive..! let me try it out on my ext4..

Comment: actually i could alter the permission to executable when i copied this file over to my home directory. so chmod worked. i then copied this modified one over to the ntfs folder where all the other files are present, to see if i can execute from there, but now the executable permission is not present. is it like i will never be able to execute this file from that ntfs folder?

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition) may help you in reaching your goal.