# How can I make a .jar file executable?

Tags: openjdk

I'm trying to run a jar application under Ubuntu, so I installed OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime, but when I open this application I got this message :

> The file '/home/aimad/Programms/jMerise/JMerise.jar' is not marked as
>   executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted
>   source, it may be dangerous to run.  For more details, read about the
>   executable bit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can always run a jar file by doing `java -jar JMerise.jar`.

However, to make the jar file itself executable, you need to set the executable bit, as the message hints. `chmod +x /home/aimad/Programms/jMerise/JMerise.jar` will accomplish this.

After that you can do `./JMerise.jar` to run it.

`man chmod` will provide you with information about how chmod works.

Also see: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/ExecutableBit

Comment: Did this ever work? `bash: ./bbb.jar: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` for `file bbb.jar` -> `bbb.jar: Java archive data (JAR)`

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the file, click on properties, then go to the Permissions tab, and check the box that says "Allow executing this file as a program".

[image]

Comment: What about if I can't check that box above, to "allow executing file as a program"? I do check it, but a moment later it automatically gets unchecked!

Comment: @user961627 You probably have the .jar file stored on a partition which doesn't support the executable bit. See [Can't make a file executable](https://askubuntu.com/q/152607/301745) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

Since you run your jar application with `java -jar application.jar` then that means java is on your path. You need two simple things:
1) add an interpreter (which apparently is `#!java -jar`) in the first line of your jar file jut like you do that with your shell scripts: 

`echo '#!java -jar' > app.jar
cat application.jar >> app.jar
mv app.jar application.jar`

If you cat the contents of your jar file you'll see it starts with ex.:
`#!java -jar
PK
    ^lN                  BOOT-INF/PK 
.....
.....`

2) add execute attribute by `chmod +x application.jar`
Now you are able to "self-run" it via `./application.jar`.

Answer (score 4):

First you'll need to make sure you have a suitable Java runtime environment on your system. Ubuntu has openjdk in the official repo which is 99.99% combatible with Oracle Java, to install it type:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`

Next create a file called `java-jar-launcher.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` and put the following contents in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Java Application Launcher
Icon=java
Exec=/usr/bin/java -jar %U
Categories=Application;Java
Terminal=False
```

Next add the following line in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`:

`application/x-java-archive=java-jar-launcher.desktop;`

Now you should be able to just double click jar files to launch them, if nothing happens then right click on a jar file, select properties then  go to the "Open With" tab and there you should see "Java Application Launcher", select that.

This method is prefferable (IMHO) because this way you are not giving execute permissions to jar files which can be potentially dangerous. This method will only work in a graphical environment and needs the user to manually double click on the file.

Answer (score 0):

If running a .jar file from the command line works (`java -jar myFile.jar`), but double-clicking it in the GUI does not, and if `sudo chmod +x myFile.jar` appears to succeed but you still can't open with double-click, and if right-clicking the .jar file > Properties > Permissions > "Allow executing file as program" does not work (i.e., the checkbox switches back just after you click it), then probably the .jar file is on an NTFS file system, which does not allow execute permissions on a per-file basis. (You may have this problem if you dual-boot, for example, and have a shared NTFS partition between Ubuntu and Windows).

Creating a launcher (as @tusharkant15 describes) will work because behind the scenes you're executing `/usr/bin/java`, not the .jar file itself. Moving the .jar file to some other file system that is not NTFS will also work.