# How to install pmTrans

Tags: software-installation

Its kind of urgent and I am not that experienced with linux I took some advice on an other topic here on what software to use for transcription and someone mentioned "the poor mans transcriber" known as [pmTrans](https://pmtrans.codeplex.com/)

The think is that it isnt a deb package nor has it some sh or install file in it... it is supposed to work in linux I extracted the zip and the jar for linux 64bit yet there are only 2 folder there and some .so files.. please help

Comment: The file you need is the one ending in `.jar`, but it is best run directly, rather than unpacked like a .zip file. Follow Videonauth's instructions below, or try right-clicking on it to see if opening the `.jar` file with Java is listed as an option. If you get an error about it "not being executable", see the answers to the following question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270172/how-can-i-make-a-jar-file-executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just start this from terminal by typing:

```
java -jar pmTransALLOS.jar
```

You can make afterwards a shortcut by `nano ~/Desktop/pmTrans.desktop` and adding the following lines into it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=pmTrans
Comment=pmTrans
Exec=java -jar /path-to/pmTransALLOS.jar
Icon=
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Reader;
```

Comment: Is there a way to make a shortcut ?

Comment: Added to my answer.