# My .jar file run with terminal but not by "clicking"' on it

Tags: openjdk, jar

I made a little program in Java, and it run perfectly when I use the `java -jar myFile.jar` but when I use the "open with OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime" option, nothing happen.

I have no idea why it doesn't launch.
If anybody got an idea... Thank you

Comment: This has been answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270172/how-can-i-make-a-jar-file-executable

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable it to be executable. You can do that one time in terminal by giving it for example `755` permissions by

```
chmod 755 /path/javafile.jar
```

or

```
chmod +x /path/javafile.jar
```

Same you can do from the GUI by open the file properties, switch to the permission tab and set the check-mark as shown in the screen-shot.

[image]